# Error 6 Overflow on Mac VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm receiving an Error 6: Overflow on Excel 2016 for Mac on this function. The error has something to do with the stocks variable, however the problem comes not when calculating stocks, but when y want to use it's value or show it with `Debug.Print()`. Any idea what could be happening?

```
Public row As Integer
Public column As Integer
Public price As Single
Public money As Single
Public stocks As Single

Sub simulateBuys()
    stocks = 0
    money = 100
    ' I've reduced the function to be readable, the Call buy() agruments are calculated in other functions
    Call buy(29, 6)
    ' The problem appears here, when i want to use the result calculated in the buy() function
    Worksheets("EMA 9 vs 26 Numeros").Cells(4, 4).Value = stocks
End Sub

Sub buy(ByRef row As Integer, ByRef column As Integer)
    ' In this case, price happens to be 100
    price = Worksheets("Price").Cells(row, column).Value
    ' The division is 100 / 100
    stocks = money / price
    Debug.Print "done"
End Sub
```

Comment: `row` and `column` should be `Long`.

Comment: I imagine Price could be equal to 0 at some point, blowing up stocks = money / price